# creating excel file and sheet with timestamp in ssis

Tags: excel, ssis

How to create Excel filename AND sheetname with timestamp in ssis,
which I am getting data from oledb source...

Comment: Creating excel outside of excel itself can be a real pain. Even though you can do it through SSIS packages via ODBC (or OLE depending you version of SSIS), depending on your needs you're likely to have to create some VBA scripts as well. Some versions of SSIS (2012 for sure) has a bug and the excel instance remains open even when the process is finished. The best solution in my experience is to create a CSV file instead. Easy to create and can be open in excel, no problem.

Comment: thanks for your suggession @J.B.,but it was my requirement....